# Can we use the Mapkit map to show navigation of route from our App instead of calling some navigation app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I want create an application which will show the user the route and provide navigation functionality from my own app(without opening any other navigation app). I have read that there is no such feature provided. Any suggestions on this??

Comment: yes , you can do this..

Comment: You should see the _Putting Map Kit in Perspective_ video in the [WWDC 2013 session videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/), which talks about how to do this.